# MVC 4: Using jtable to create table

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jtable, jsonresult

I have this table in database called `Modules` which looks like
[image: Database table]

To interact with database I use entity framework and here is what I have done

```
public class SISContext : SoramaCoreContext
    {
        public SISContext()
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current == null)
            {
                Database.SetInitializer<SISContext>(null);
            }
        }
        public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
    }
```

I have very less or no knowledge on using jtable. I just saw some tutorial at [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277576/AJAX-based-CRUD-tables-using-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jTa)

I came to know that I have to pass `JsonResult` to make `jtable` to work
My Module model looks like this

```
 public class Module
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long ModuleTypeId { get; set; }
        public ModuleType ModuleType { get; set; }
        public string ModuleId { get; set; }
        public PropertyConfiguration PropertyConfiguration { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateEntered { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is what i've tried to do in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Module> modules = _db.Modules.ToList();//Don't even know if this collects all the data from table....Any suggestion how to do it?
                return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = modules });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Json(new {Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message});
            }

        }
```

and this is what I tried to do in my view, right now I just want to show `ModuleId` and `DateEntered` in the view through jtable as a tryout.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.basic.cshtml";
}
@section head{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jtable.2.2.0/themes/metro/blue/jtable.css")" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
}    
<div id="ModuleTable" style="width: 580px; margin: auto;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ModuleTable').jtable({
            title: 'Module List',
            fields: {
                ModuleId: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                DateEntered: {
                    title: 'Date Entered',
                    Width: '15%'
                }
            }
        });
        $('#ModuleTable').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
```

I know what I'm doing is wrong, but may be I can get some nice help here to get started.

Currently I get a error :

```
HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 
So, basically I want to show the table in in picture in my view using jtable.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not given the action tag

eg :-

```
actions: {
    listAction: '/Health/BasicList',
    deleteAction: '/Health/DeleteBasic',
    updateAction: '/Health/UpdateBasic',
    createAction: '/Health/CreateBasic'
},
```

Put it in between title and fields, in this scenario Health is my Controller and BasicList is my controller method or action method .